# Data manipulation on multiple FTPs simultaneosly

Tags: php, ftp

Let me show you the code first so that you can understand what I am talking about:

```
foreach($video_ftps as $video_ftp) {
  $ftp = new FtpClient($video_ftp[0]);
  $ftp->set_writing_destination($video_ftp[1]);
  if($ftp) {

    if($ftp->create_new_dir('archive'))
      $utils->log("Created directory '/archive' on source.");

    $tmp_ftp = new FtpClient($video_ftp[1]);
    $tmp_ftp->create_new_dir('video');
    $tmp_ftp->create_new_dir('video/'.$video_ftp[2]);
    $tmp_ftp->close();

    // Check if new files arrived on ftp
    if($ftp->has_new_files())
    {
      foreach($ftp->fetch_new_file() as $file) {
        $checksum_source = "";
        $checksum_dest = "";
        if($ftp->copy(MODE_SAME_FTP, $file, 'archive'))
          $checksum_source = sha1_file($video_ftp[0].'/'.$file);
          $utils->log("Copied {$file} to {$ftp->get_writing_destination()}archive/.");

        $fileExtension = explode(".", $file)[1];
        if($fileExtension == "mp4") {
          if($ftp->rename($file , $video_ftp[1].'video/'.$video_ftp[2].'/'.$file))
            $checksum_dest = sha1_file($video_ftp[1].'video/'.$video_ftp[2].'/'.$file);
            if($checksum_source != $checksum_dest) {
              $tmp_ftp = new FtpClient($video_ftp[1]);
              $tmp_ftp->copy(MODE_DIFF_FTP, 'video/'.$video_ftp[2].'/'.$file, $video_ftp[0].'/'.$file);
              $tmp_ftp->delete('video/'.$video_ftp[2].'/'.$file);
              $tmp_ftp->close();
            } else {
              $utils->log("Moved {$file} file to {$ftp->get_writing_destination()}{$video_ftp[1]}'video/'{$video_ftp[2]}/.");
            }
        }
        
      }
    }

    $ftp->close();
  }
}
```

*Note: The FTPClient class just does the same thing as all ftp_* functions. The class just removes the prefixes and makes it object oriented.*

So. Just leave what is happening inside the loop. Take it as an FTP is being manipulated and files are being deleted, moved and copied from within the FTP and different FTPs.

One thing you need to understand is the loop. I have ftp connection strings in `$video_ftps` and I sequentially cater each one them and manipulate it.

What I want to do is that each different FTP should be in a different thread and should be manipulating simultaneously with other FTPs.

I read about threading in PHP but could not find or understand anything related to it. Can you tell me how could I transform this loop based thing into a threading based thing.

### UPDATE 1:

I created a separate file of the manipulations part of the ftp:

```
<?php

require 'FtpClient.php';
require 'Utils.php';

$video_ftp = array($argv[0], $argv[1], $argv[2]);

$ftp = new FtpClient($video_ftp[0]);
$ftp->set_writing_destination($video_ftp[1]);
if($ftp) {

  if($ftp->create_new_dir('archive'))
    $utils->log("Created directory '/archive' on source.");

  $tmp_ftp = new FtpClient($video_ftp[1]);
  $tmp_ftp->create_new_dir('video');
  $tmp_ftp->create_new_dir('video/'.$video_ftp[2]);
  $tmp_ftp->close();

  // Check if new files arrived on ftp
  if($ftp->has_new_files())
  {
    foreach($ftp->fetch_new_file() as $file) {
      $checksum_source = "";
      $checksum_dest = "";
      if($ftp->copy(MODE_SAME_FTP, $file, 'archive'))
        $checksum_source = sha1_file($video_ftp[0].'/'.$file);
        $utils->log("Copied {$file} to {$ftp->get_writing_destination()}archive/.");

      $fileExtension = explode(".", $file)[1];
      if($fileExtension == "mp4") {
        if($ftp->rename($file , $video_ftp[1].'video/'.$video_ftp[2].'/'.$file))
          $checksum_dest = sha1_file($video_ftp[1].'video/'.$video_ftp[2].'/'.$file);
          if($checksum_source != $checksum_dest) {
            $tmp_ftp = new FtpClient($video_ftp[1]);
            $tmp_ftp->copy(MODE_DIFF_FTP, 'video/'.$video_ftp[2].'/'.$file, $video_ftp[0].'/'.$file);
            $tmp_ftp->delete('video/'.$video_ftp[2].'/'.$file);
            $tmp_ftp->close();
          } else {
            $utils->log("Moved {$file} file to {$ftp->get_writing_destination()}{$video_ftp[1]}'video/'{$video_ftp[2]}/.");
          }
      }
      
    }
  }

  $ftp->close();
}
```

?>

And I updated my previous file to run this function instead of the code I shifted to a separate file:

```
exec("php video_ftp_manipulator.php ". $video_ftp[0] . "" . $video_ftp[1] . "" . $video_ftp[2] . " > /dev/null &");
```

The problem coming now is that now nothing is happening when I run my file. Nothing is changing in the FTP. Why is that so?

Comment: `ftp`? in 2015? ouch....

Comment: PHP is not multi-threaded. there's libraries which can add various levels of threading support, but the core language is NOT multithreaded.

Comment: Ok, so how would I implement such thing in it?

Comment: @arkascha what's so strange about ftp in 2015??

Comment: `ftp` is a protocol from the 70th. It is a nightmare for all administrators these days, since it is somewhat chaotic in its view of the network topology. It offers no protection of your data, since it is not encrypted (yes I know about ''ftps'', but that only encrypts the data channel, not the actual data).There are replacements which make much more sense: `sftp`, `webdavs`, `fish`, `rsync` and others, so there is no need to cling to this old implementation.

Comment: @arkascha nevertheless, it ain't my thing. It's my client's. xD

Comment: Also 90% (I just made that number up) of sites are still deployed using ftp...

Answer (score 3):

**There is no need for any threading.**

The problem is, your abstraction of FTP is poor, I suggest you ditch it and use the extension directly.

The FTP extension comes equipped with non-blocking functions to facilitate asynchronous requests, use them:

- [non-blocking put](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-put.php)
- [non-blocking get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-get.php)
- [non-blocking continue](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-continue.php)

That is all you should need.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't intrinsically do asynchronous requests, although there are ways to accomplish simulated multithreading by trigging separate child scripts using exec() or shell_exec() in PHP, passing arguments to the child scripts, and sending their output to /dev/null, so PHP won't wait for a response before continuing. **While possible, it's not ideal (and I don't recommend it), since there is no efficient way to get useful data back from the child scripts**.

One could use exec() inside a loop to trigger another script from a shell command. Example use:

`exec("php child.php argument1 argument2 > /dev/null &");`

Here I'm running child.php as a shell script, passing it arguments there could be additional arguments. I'm sending the output to /dev/null, so php won't wait for it.

In my child PHP script, I'll need to use the following to get the argument strings:

`$first_arg = $argv[1];
$second_arg = $argsv[2];`

The arguments could be an ftp server and filename, or you could add arguments to specify an action to be taken by the child script...

Comment: Can you tell me how please? :)

Comment: `exec("php childphp argument > /dev/null &");` will run a child script called child.php as a shell script, and pass it "argument."  Argument could be an ftp server.  Since the output is sent to >/dev/null instead of being returned, PHP won't wait for the response, so your parent script could spin up a bunch of instances/threads of test.php

Comment: I see the update.  Does the ftp server allow multiple connections from the same user?  This is what I was saying about this not being ideal.  Since you're essentially spinning off the separate threads and sending output to no man's land, you don't have an easy way to diagnose problems, and no easy way to verify that the actions you're requesting of the child scripts were successful. I've only ever used this approach when I didn't have to be overly concerned about the outcomes in different threads.